# How can I chose folder where I want save files in C#

Tags: c#

In my app, I have 3 buttons and 2 textboxes, so when I press first button I can chose file. Then I suppose to chose folder where I want to save that file, and I don't know how to do that. And third button copy .txt files and delete some parts from them, and move to folder which I suppose to chose with button2.

So this is my first button,  and it is ok!
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

```
    private void btn_Chose_File_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && openFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            txtb_Input_Folder.Text = ofd.FileName;                
        }
    }
```

So when I press second button i suppose to chose directory where I want to save file, and path should be written in textbox2. Same as in first step. So can someone help me? I tried with SaveFileDialog but it doesn't work because I just want to select directory, not to save.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

GetFileName() returns the full path

OpenDialog are only to open a file.
SaveDialog are to write the file to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FolderBrowserDialog` class. It will choose directory only.

Comment: Yes that is correct answer. I fix problem with it, but now I have one problem, I miss "/" on the end of directory(Example C:\Track Usage\Out FIleRegistration.txt). So now I need to insert "\" between "Folder" and File .

Comment: string full_name = fb.SelectedPath; if (!full_name.EndsWith("\\")) full_name += "\\"; full_name += file;

Comment: PS: Note that if you select root folder (e.g. `C:\ `) you will have `\ ` at the end of `SelectedPath` and there is no need to add extra `\ `.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but I am beginner sry. What is fb?

Comment: `fb` is sample `FolderBrowserDialog` object. It is usually with name `folderBrowserDialog1` when auto generated by VS.

Comment: Ok. Thank You. I fix my problems. Almost everything is fine now.